# Particolar solutions to a 4-variables diophantine equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Studying a certain problem, I came across the Diophantine equation $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 3t^2$. How can I find the solutions to the latter with the further condition that $(x,y,z,t)$ are pairwise coprime? I know that they must be all odds, and that $t$ is the only one that can be a multiple of 3. Do they have other properties? Obviously it admits solutions, such as the trivial $(1,1,1,1)$.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Must $x,y,z,t$ be positive and integer?

Comment: Yes, by symmetry we can restrict the case to all positive integers.

Comment: Note I found the duplicate through using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24x%5E2%2By%5E2%2Bz%5E2%3D3t%5E2%24&p=1) (although as a link from its search result of [Pythagorean Quadruples:](/q/463266)). This other question gives a parametric solution, which doesn't require that $(x,y,z,t)$ be pairwise coprime. However, it does include non-trivial coprime solutions, such as with its $r=1$, $s=t=2$ giving $x=13$, $y=5$, $z=7$ and $t=9$. Checking, we get $169+25+49=243=3\times 81$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Oh, thanks, I didn't know of approach0 tool. I'm going to use it from now on.